# How to remove the blur/leak in some edges and color discrepancies for this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile

I have this image exported for the web from Photoshop CC 2015, but it has a couple of issues that I want to solve.

[image]

The problem is in the vertical strip in color fuchsia with a pattern of hearts in color pink.

First, when I open the image in Preview on the screen of a MacBook Air Mid 2012 the pattern with pink hearts won't show up. The strip is in a solid color, fuchsia, I guess.

If I drag the Preview window to an eternal monitor, HP w22, or place the window one half on the laptop display and the other half of the monitor, the pattern of hearts suddenly appears but only after I stop dragging the window. If I keep moving the window on the external monitor the pattern of herts won't show up either.

[image]

Second, if I open the image on my Android mobile device (Acer Iconia B1-770), there appear to be a blur or color leak between the same fuchsia strip and the curvy strip in color green to the left. It looks as if the pixels closer to the green strip were in color dark violet.

**How can I remove those discrepancies so that the image look pretty much the same in all three displays?**

These are the current settings I have for the color profile, and the image mode is RGB Color and 8 Bit/Channel.

[image]

[image]

**Update**

This is a screen-capture showing how the same image looks on Photoshop CC, Chrome, Firefox and Safari (from left to right respectively). Only Chrome seems to be rendering the image consistently on both displays (the external monitor is on the upper half).

[image]

Comment: Color calibrate your monitors. And for what it's worth, Preview is a *horrible* application and not designed  to be "accurate" in *many* instances - just dragging a jpg to a browser window will render better than Preview does in many instances.

Comment: @Metis I was able to calibrate the built-in display. The external monitor seems just too bright. With contrast at minimum and brightness at maximum the oval in the center of the gauge is still too bright compared to the right side of the image. Also the images in both the external monitor and mobile device are very similar, so maybe the problems is the gamma value in the built-in display. If I open the image on Safari, Chrome or Firefox, it looks different in all three browsers, only chrome is consistent between the two displays. I guess I need a cup of coffee!

Comment: @Metis I don't know if it's a display calibration issue. I updated the question with an image showing four different apps showing the image. It has the same embedded profile, so it is somehow related to the underlying technologies used by each application to render the image. Is there something else I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Some applications are color managed, some aren't. You will *never* be able to control the appearance of an image in every monitor in every application. There's no way of ever knowing whether a user has calibrated their monitor or what application they may be viewing your image with.

Comment: @Metis I'll have to modify the fuchsia and pink colors in the strip then. Thanks.

Comment: The in-built "by eye" calibration within windows is basically useless. You need a proper optical calibration device.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Hmmm... there should be some app to do this with the camera in my phone!?

Comment: No that cant work, pretty much every phone has a different sensor, with different colour responses, there's no way to calibrate against an unknown.